# In Rails, how do I render different content/types upon errors under different namespaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with an `/admin` namespace and an `/api` namespace (no routes in the root).

Each namespace should handle errors differently:

- The `/admin` namespace should show HTML error pages
- The `/api` namespace should always render JSON (or nothing) upon errors (a 404 or 500 should render nothing but a 400 might render validation errors in JSON)

How do I do this in Rails?